# Visual Studio 2010/2012 Git Plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, visual-studio-2012

I am looking for suggestions for a git integration with VS 2010/2012 that allow developers use the basic operations (commit, push,pull,switch branches, tagging)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Visual Studio for Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) with VS 2012, it's matured now (version 1.0).

I like deep integration with VS 2012 especially switch between branch seamlessly, you will work with any branch at any time.

Another thing is that it's working very well with Bitbucket.

Comment: For 2010/2012/2013 users, browse Tools -> Extension Manager -> Online Gallery and search for Git Source Control Provider.

Answer (score 27):

There are several:

1. [Git Source Control Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c)
2. [Visual Studio Tools for Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c)  a.k.a. *Microsoft Git Provider* from Microsoft.
3. [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/)

1 and 2 gives you deep integration with the source control UI of Visual Studio, like padlock icons on files:

[image: File icons showing git status]

1 uses the ordinary *Pending Changes* tab, but adds some functions, like *Switch Branch*:

[image: Pending changes in Git Source Control Provider]

2 surely represents the future of Git integration in Visual Studio since Microsoft is behind it.

[image: Microsoft Git Provider changes tab]

Note that 2 requires Visual Studio 2012 (with update 2 even), so if VS2010 support is a requirement you cannot use it. 2 is built into Visual Studio 2013

However, it sounds like you might prefer 3. *Git Extensions* is simpler and just gives you a simple toolbar with commit, pull, push, stash (not switch branch, though):

[image: Git Extensions toolbar]

Comment: I think Microsoft's Visual Studio Tools for Git requires VS 2012.

Comment: Microsoft Git Provider current version (also built-in VS 2013) conflicts with ReSharper: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792497/visual-studio-tools-for-git-microsoft-git-provider-v0-9-0-0-blocks-resharper-refactoring#tabs

Comment: For 2010 users, Got with Git Source Control Provider. It is easy to use and install.
Run Visual Studio.
Go to Tools | Extension Manager, search online gallery for Git Source Control Provider and install.