# Is there VS analogue for vim's powerline?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, statusbar

I want something like these ones, but in VS

- https://github.com/bling/vim-airline
- https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline

Namely, I would like to see git branch, git status, saved/modified status of current sln.

---

**UPD**: I'm addicted to reducing visual clutter in UI, so my VS looks like this:
[image: VS screenshot]

I've recently fallen in love with [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/default.aspx) and the way it puts all the info I need in just a small portion of status bar (instead of other runners which looks more like a plane cockpit). So, I though that it would be awesome to put all the git info there as well, because all I actually need is [Posh-Git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)-like prompt: `[master +0 ~2 -1 | +1 ~1 -0]` plus `saved/modified`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there isn't, so I've started writing [my own](https://github.com/vorou/githere).

**UPD**: it's [alive](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0344701c-45e4-4b3b-8d2b-92e5c8ad5bbe)

**UPD2**: use VS 2015 Update1 instead [image: i]

Answer (score 2):

There are several git plugins for Visual Studio, as I have [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989962/visual-studio-2010-2012-git-plugin/16990006#16990006).

If you install [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) you get a status bar in Visual Studio that shows the current branch:

[image: Git Extensions toolbar]

If you install the [Git Source Control Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c) you get a Pending Changes tab that shows current branch in the tab header:

[image: Git Source Control Provider tab header]

Both the Git Source Control Provider and the [Microsoft Git Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) shows what files in the solution  have been modified by decorating the icons:

[image: File icon modifiers]

But I haven't seen anything that shows the `git status` in a toolbar inside Visual Studio. I usually have Git Extensions open for that. The *Commit* button shows status by colour and modified files by number:

[image: Git Extensions toolbar]

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply, but it looks like neither of these tools will do what I'm looking for (see my update).

Comment: I think I get what you want, I just don't think it is out there. I like your idea. I hope someone writes such an extension to VS.